# Adding key-value pairs to TreeMap in value sorted order

Tags: java, sorting, collections, treemap

Assuming the key-value pairs are coming from a stream, and we are reading them one by one and adding them to a TreeMap that needs to be sorted by value then key, how can I achieve this? I am not talking about any intermediary map using which I can write a Comparator easily to fetch corresponding value from this map and use it in sorting logic. Its not permissible. Directly, how its possible. I dont think its possible without using another data structure. Or I am goofing it up somewhere? Any suggestion!

Take this example:

> apple, 2
>   banana, 20
>   orange, 5

it should be in tree as:

> apple, 2
>   orange, 5
>   banana, 20

Comment: The javadoc for TreeMap is explicit: `A Red-Black tree based NavigableMap implementation. The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.`  So it's sorting by keys only, unless you provide a comparator.  That being said, you could just use a TreeMap with a custom comparator, unless this is also not permissible.

Answer (score 0):

If only usage of additional structures is not allowed then I would use synthetic keys in your tree map that contain both original key and value from your data source. In this case you will have something like:

```
[key, value] -> value
```

It won't use much more memory since you refer the same value object in both places. And it requires to have custom comparator which compares value parts from synthetic keys.

So in the end you have to define two more classes.

PS: Of course you won't be able use this map to find value by original keys anymore. It will only by useful in ordering key-value pairs. In this way it would be even better to use TreeSet with key-value pairs as elements.